# Adding custom brush handles in D3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add some custom elements to the handles of a brush in a D3 project I'm working on — [the desired final result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJAk3.png) — and I've been stymied by D3 V4's move from `<g>` elements for brush handles to `<rect>` elements. The V4 docs say that you can add, remove, or modify the brush handles using the `.handle--*` class, but I haven't been able to get that to work. For example, when I invoke:

```
const brushContainer = d3.select('#brushContainer');
brushContainer.call(d3.brushX());
brushContainer.selectAll('.handle').remove();
brushContainer.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'handle handle--w');
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.type')
```

Note that I wouldn't necessarily *expect* the above code to work, but I haven't been able to find any working examples, or any clues in the docs or the source.

*Edit:* I just had the idea of appending the required `<g>`s independently, then changing their `x` attributes to `d3.event.selection` on `brush`. I'd like to be able to use the `<g>`s as handles, and this approach leaves them without click handlers, but if this is the Canonical Right Answer, I'll just go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are supposed to add and position the handles independently with the brush event.

https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/issues/14